# how to ignore spaces in c# regex

Tags: c#

what is the c# equivalent of /x in perl for regex, so the /x at the end would ignore all the whitespaces newlines and whatnot in your regex expression.  Otherwise, my expression would be a giant one liner instead of a little block.  Any other way around it?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's an option you can specify when constructing the `Regex`:

```
new Regex("...expression here...", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

Since `RegexOptions` is a flag type, you can binary-OR this flag with any existing flags you may specify.

Answer (score 0):

The /x inline character is supported.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).